# Phonegap HTML5 Video Tag iOS

Tags: ios, html, angularjs, cordova, vimeo

Hopefully an easy question. Using Phonegap 3.5, Angular UI. Trying to user HTML5 Video tag. Coded as:

```
<video ng-src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/11336811"></video>
```

The page loades with the play button with a slash through it. When I run through Safari debugging I get the following error in the angualar-1.2.0-rc3.js:

```
Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e(a,function(){})')
```

That doesn't help me much. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using an `iframe` instead of a `video` tag?

Comment: Yes, that works, was wondering if the video tag worked in phonegap.